# (SQL) find oldest person in table (avoid hard code)

Tags: mysql, sql, hardcode

I'm trying to find the oldest person at my table. And I have all person's birthdates.

I write code like this:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(day, birthdate, '2021-09-12') AS 'Age'
FROM table
ORDER BY age
limit 1
```

but I think this is hard-coding. How can I improve my code?

Answer (score 2):

The oldest person would be the one with minimum birth date. You don't need `TIMESTAMPDIFF` at all, you just order by `birthdate asc` and take `limit 1`.

Comment: You want ascending not descending, otherwise you'll end up with the youngest.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `timestampdiff` - just order the query by `birthdate` and take the smallest (earliest) one:

```sql
SELECT   *
FROM     mytable
ORDER BY birthdate ASC
LIMIT    1
```

Comment: Thank you!! Also may I use to code 'MIN(DATE)'?

Comment: @island1996 you don't need a `min` call there - just query the `birthdate` - since you're ordering and taking the first row, it will be the smallest.

Answer (score 0):

No need to calculate the age in days for this purpose, as stated by others. However, if you wanted to continue with your solution, which calculates the age of a person in days, you could deploy the following solution:

```sql
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(day, birthdate, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS 'Age' 
FROM table ORDER BY age DESC limit 1
```

Comment: Thank you!!! And may I ask if I calculate the age, is my code a hard code?

Comment: No. When we refer to some values as "hard coded" we mean to say that providing specific values, such as today's date in your example, reduces the code's flexibity. This new solution is not hard coded since the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` adapts to the current timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

you should also change the fixed date to curdate() which would automatically select the actual date

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(day, birthdate, CURDATE()) AS 'Age'
FROM table1
ORDER BY birthdate DESC
limit 1
```